# priority queue, why is it still printing the last element

Tags: c++, priority-queue

This is my first time working with queue's and dequeue's. The concept is simple but I am having a problem when I am trying to use STL.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <queue>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    priority_queue<int> pq;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        int t = rand() % 100;
        cout << "Pushing " << t << " on top of queue." << endl;  
        pq.push(t);
    }
    while(!pq.empty()){
        cout << pq.top() << " : is on top of queue " << endl;
        pq.pop();   
    }

    if(pq.empty()){
        cout << pq.top() << endl;
        cout << "list is empty" << endl;    
    }
    pq.pop();
    cout << pq.top() << endl;
    return 0;   
}
```

I wanted to see what is printed if the queue is empty but when I do that it always prints the last element.My output looks like this.

```
Pushing 58 on top of queue.
Pushing 89 on top of queue.
Pushing 76 on top of queue.
Pushing 38 on top of queue.
Pushing 21 on top of queue.
Pushing 69 on top of queue.
Pushing 25 on top of queue.
Pushing 49 on top of queue.
Pushing 58 on top of queue.
Pushing 59 on top of queue.
89 : is on top of queue 
76 : is on top of queue 
69 : is on top of queue 
59 : is on top of queue 
58 : is on top of queue 
58 : is on top of queue 
49 : is on top of queue 
38 : is on top of queue 
25 : is on top of queue 
21 : is on top of queue 
21
list is empty
21
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening. Why it is printing 21 even when the list is completely empty. From my intuition the last element is stored somewhere in the buffer, if the queue is empty and if one tries to access the empty queue this element is printed out.

Answer (score 5):

`top` can only be called on a non-empty queue. Calling it when the queue is empty causes Undefined Behaviour, meaning anything can happen.

Comment: But to my surprise it is the last element of the queue every time which may be seen as a defined behavior if I am not wrong. I may be wrong though. Thank you :)

Comment: @Phaneeth *Undefined behaviour is undefined.* It's perfectly possible that with your compiler's standard library implementation, your compiler version, your processor architecture, and your current compilation flags, the result is always the last popped element. But you cannot rely on this, and it could change as soon as anything about your situation changes. A program with UB cannot be relied upon.

Comment: Got it. Thanks @Angew

Answer (score 0):

Try it again with this small modification:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <queue>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct Foo
{
    Foo(int x) : p(std::make_unique<int>(x)) {}
    std::unique_ptr<int> p;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Foo& f)
{
    return os << *f.p;
}

bool operator<(const Foo& l,const Foo& r)
{
    return *(l.p) < *(r.p);
}


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    priority_queue<Foo> pq;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        auto t = Foo(rand() % 100);
        cout << "Pushing " << t << " on top of queue." << endl;
        pq.push(std::move(t));
    }
    while(!pq.empty()){
        cout << pq.top() << " : is on top of queue " << endl;
        pq.pop();
    }

    if(pq.empty()){
        cout << pq.top() << endl;
        cout << "list is empty" << endl;
    }
    pq.pop();
    cout << pq.top() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Then let's have a discussion about Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: I am up for it, go on @Richard Hodges

Comment: @Phaneeth I think Richard is suggesting you run his alternative version and see the effect the UB have cause ...